# Make Span Element Disappear with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<span id="block1">
anything
<a onclick="FUNCTION()"><button>Do Magic</button></a>
</span>

<span id="block2">
magic
</span>
```

I need block1 to disappear and block2 to appear. How would I do this?

Comment: Please show us the code of your `FUNCTION` and what particular problem you have with it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Comment: @Bergi I think they don't have a `FUNCTION` yet, hence the question.

Comment: I don't have "FUNCTION ()" I ask you to write it

Comment: @ЖакФреско StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We can help you understand and overcome problems in your code, but you need to try something yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `block1` disappear by setting it's `style` to `display: none;` and make `block2` appear by setting it's style to `display: block;`.

```js
function magic() {
    document.getElementById('block1').style = 'display: none;'
    document.getElementById('block2').style = 'display: block;'
}
```

```html
<span id="block1">
anything
<a onclick="magic()"><button>Do magic</button></a>
</span>
<span id="block2" style="display: none;">
magic
</span>
```

Comment: Okey,nice. I have this problem: https://i.imgur.com/chROJBY.jpg

My code: https://i.imgur.com/c6QIiGh.jpg